# Hystrix dashboard keeps loading in Cloud foundry even though it works in local

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, cloud-foundry, hystrix

I have built .net core microservices and deployed in PCF. I have implemented the hystrix circuitbreaker using Pivotal steeltoe framework and Eureka Service discovery.

While running locally on my computer, it all works well, I get the ciruit-breaker to work as desired and see the Hystrix dashboard showing the right graphs.

Problem comes when I deploy the same to Pivotal Cloud foundry. In PCF, everything else works just as fine( service discovery is alright, I can make requests to my microservices, can see circuit breaker working as desired as it does on my local), but **I can NOT find a way to get the Hystrix dashboard working. It keeps showing "loading..." instead of showing graphs.**

Just for reference, I still can see the stream data in browser being streamed by my app running on PCF. I am using following URL to feed the stream to Hystrix dashboard:

```
https://my-cloudfoundry-app-route/hystrix/hystrix.stream
```

any idea  what could I be doing wrong here? anyone else had such a problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: found it myself, just had to change the reference of nuget:

Comment: http://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-circuitbreaker/#1-1-2-9-use-a-hystrix-dashboard .... following changes needed to be made in nuget references: _Steeltoe.CircuitBreaker.Hystrix.MetricsStreamCore_ (when targeting **Cloud Foundry**) or _Steeltoe.CircuitBreaker.Hystrix.MetricsEventsCore_ (when running **locally**)